# How to do faceted search in Sitecore 7.x?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, faceted-search

Can anyone point me to some documentation that gives a step by step explanation of how to do faceted search in `Sitecore 7.x`? I have read the official Sitecore documentation (Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search).

I have found that document to be very confusing.  Chapter 2 is all about Item Buckets.  Well, I don't need Item Buckets for this project.  I don't have that many content items.  Chapter 3 is called "Searching", but I think it is talking all about searching for content items in Item Buckets from within in the Sitecore interface.

That is interesting - but not what I need.  Chapter 5 is about developing with Item Buckets. But it is very unclear to me when they are talking about searching within the Sitecore interface and when they are talking about building search in your website.

What I am looking for is a clear step by step explanation of how to set up indexes and facets and then specific code examples for how to perform a faceted search.  Does anyone know if this exists anywhere online?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good set of blogs and Google Hangouts done by the Sitecore development team for the release of Sitecore 7 (in which the new search features were introduced). You can access those here: http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/10/Facets-Explained.aspx

In terms of setting up indexes, use the configuration files provided, namely the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config, and play with the configuration as required. By default you will have three indexes set up already (sitecore_content_web, sitecore_content_core, and sitecore_content_master). If you want to customise, then just edit the current configuration. The Locations section of the index configuration is most relevant, and the nodes should be self explanatory, but the main ones are;

- Root: Defines where in the Sitecore content tree will be indexed (e.g. Sitecore/Content/MyStuff)
- Database: Specifies which database (Master, Web, or Core) is used

You can have many crawlers per index, but you probably don't need to, and I wouldn't start with that.

With regards to faceting, this is mainly driven by the Linq extension 'FacetOn'. This can be applied to a Linq query on your index as such:

```
        using (IProviderSearchContext context =  ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Constants._webContentIndexName).CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var model = new SearchResultViewModel();

            //Get all items in home ordered by content data
            //Faceted on semantics so will work with tagging
            IQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem> query =     context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>()
                .Where(i => i.Path.StartsWith(Constants._startPath))
                .Where(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm))
                .Where(i => i.TemplateId != exclusionTemplate)
                .FacetOn(i => i.Semantics);

            //DO SOMETHING WITH RESULTS

        }
```

Just to clarify any confusion, when the documents refer to Item Buckets etc, this is no different to how you will perform a search. The great thing about Sitecore is that even the GUI's are built on the same API's you use to develop your solution. So where the internal search is developed around Item Buckets, you can use these examples in your own search solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any information that anyone gives me is helpful! I read that link that you provided and I didn't really get anything out of it.  I must be missing something fundamental that everyone else already understands.  :)  In your code example above what is SearchResultViewModel? I think maybe I need some simple documentation on how to use the SitecoreContentSearch API.  The faceting part seems simple enough.  But I am having trouble even understanding how to get the basics set up and working.

Comment: Yep appreciate I may be assuming some prior knowledge. Sitecore is quite a large platform so I understand sometimes things can take a while to get your head around. Rather than edit my answer, I found another good reference that I think covers everything: http://www.fusionworkshop.co.uk/news-and-insight/tech-lab/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide#.VI7-OCs76BY